# Compare elements of two arrays in less than O(n^2) time?

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o

I have two integer arrays. I need to find out two numbers, one from each array, whose sum is equal to 2. This is very simple in O(n^2) but is there a way to do it faster?

Comment: Sort each O(2 x n log(n)) then O(N+M)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in O(N+M) time and O(N) space like this:

- Put elements of array `a` into a hash set
- Walk through array `b`, and check if hash table contains `2-b[i]`

Constructing a hash set of `N` elements takes O(N) time and O(N) space. Checking each of `M` elements against the hash set takes O(1), for a total of O(N+M) time.

Comment: HashTable.Contains(int) (i.e. searching the HashTable for a key), would not that take O(N) time, and for each element in N list, it would produce O(n^2)?

Comment: @BassemAkl Hash table containment check is O(1).

Comment: thanks! I searched to find your statement is true. It is good info to add.

Comment: Good idea, we don't have the space requirements though